# Python Curve_Fit with Bars

Tags: python, curve-fitting

We are given Ic values that are mA range and of the order of magnitude .1~2 mA and there is a Gaussian distribution among them as the Magnetic Field is swept from -1500 t0 1500.

I found this Curve_Fitting code through Python documentation that does the fit, but was wondering if it is possible to do curve fitting for Bars in Python?

```
def func(x, I, CorrectedBitSize, Lambda, M):
    return I * abs(
        2 * sp.jv(1, (
            (float(CorrectedBitSize) * (
                2 * abs(Lambda) + 2 * dN + dF) * (x + M)) /
            (phi0 * math.pow(10, 10)))) / (
            (float(CorrectedBitSize) * (
                2 * Lambda + 2 * dN + dF) * (x + M)) /
            (phi0 * math.pow(10, 10))
        )
    )

dF = 2 * math.pow(10, -9)  # thickness
dN = 5 * math.pow(10, -9)  # thickness
mu0 = 4 * math.pi * math.pow(10, -7)  # constant
phi0 = 6.62607 * math.pow(10, -34) / (2 * 1.6 * math.pow(10, -19))
Ic_Bins_pos = np.array(random);
Ic_Bins_Field_Pos = np.array(-1500, 1500)
Lambda = (0.00000009)

best_vals, covar = curve_fit(func, Ic_Bins_Field_pos, Ic_Bins_pos, sigma=.2)
# popt, pcov = leastsq(func, Ic_Bins_Field_pos, Ic_Bins_pos)

y = func(Ic_Bins_Field_pos, *best_vals)
x = np.linspace(-1500, 1500, len(y))
y_noise = 0.2 * x
yfit = y_noise + y

plt.plot(Ic_Bins_Field_pos, yfit, c='g')
# plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you have example or an attempted example with it in Bars?

Comment: What do you mean by "Bars"?